# Dependency injection issue in Apache Ignite cache event listener and EJB

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ignite

I have a Startup+Singleton EJB in which I need to inject an object. In the PostConstruct method of this EJB, I need to register a remote cache event listener for an Ignite grid. The "apply" method of this listeners should call a method of the injected object.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class RegisterEventListeners {
    @Inject
    private EventListenerDelegate listenerDelegate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("ignite-config.xml");
        registerRemoteEventListener(ignite);
    }

    public void registerRemoteEventListener(final Ignite ignite) {
        IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> remoteListener = new IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent>() {
            public boolean apply(CacheEvent e) {
                listenerDelegate.respondToCacheEvent(ignite, e);
                return ignite.affinity("IgniteCache").isPrimary(ignite.culster().localNode(), e.key());
            }
        };

        ignite.events(ignite.cluster().forCacheNodes("IgniteCache")).remoteListen(null, remoteListener, EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT);
    }
}
```

In the EventListenerDelegate class, I am further injecting something else which will eventually do something with the retrieved cache event. The reason I am passing the Ignite object also to the respondToCacheEvent method of this class, is because I am issuing a cache.remove within this method. So its easy to quickly get a handle for the cache if I pass the Ignite object itself. Hope that is not a problem.

This deploys just fine. But when I put something on the cache, I get a NullPointerException on the "listenerDelegate.respondToCacheEvent" line in the "apply" method. This clearly means that when Ignite did the registration of the listener, the CDI injection had not happened by that time. Or may be the problem is something else entirely.

Is what I am doing correct? How else can I ensure that all injects happen properly and then the remoteListener is registered?

Comment: I have the exact same problem as yours. It seems that when an event is received, Ignite creates (ie calls new) a new instance of the containing class and then call the method referenced in the listen, totally ignoring the CDI lifecycles. In the listening method no injection is done and there is no cdi context. CDI.current() returns null!! help!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, turns out I need default constructors for classes whose objects I want to be injected in other classes :(

I did not know that. After adding empty no-arg constructors for my EventListenerDelegate class, all is well!

Sorry for wasting your time :(

Answer (score 0):

`remoteListener` is serialized and sent to remote nodes when Ignite event listener is registered. So `listenerDelegate` has to be injected before `registerRemoteEventListener` method is called, but it looks like it's `null` at that moment.

Can you check if this the case?

Comment: That is what the error seems to suggest. This is what the question is about in fact. Why is it null. registerRemoteEventListener is called inside a PostConstruct method; so by the time this is called, all Inject and everything should have been taken care of by the container (JBoss in this case) right?

Comment: That's right. And from my understanding this means that the code you provided is correct and the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: If I remove Inject annotations and create the objects myself using `new` then everything works fine. So this is clearly related to injection not happening before PostConstruct method is called, which does not make sense :(